# Django 1.5: django-registration email a unique field?

Tags: django, django-registration

I use Django 1.5 + django-registration 0.9...

How to make email field unique in model User?

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'registration.views.register',
    {'form_class': RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,
     'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'},       
     name='registration_register'),
```

This solution is not suitable

```
Could not import registration.views.register. View does not exist in module registration.views.
```

Comment: You can extend `AbstractBaseUser` model and create your own user model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909819/django-registration-form-and-registration-unique-email-form

Comment: @Bibhas django-registration 0.9 wants to work with a extend user model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many thanks, @Alasdair
[How to use different view for django-registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379300/how-to-use-different-view-for-django-registration?rq=1)

urls.py:

```
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

class RegistrationViewUniqueEmail(RegistrationView):
    form_class = RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^user/register', RegistrationViewUniqueEmail.as_view(),
                    name='registration_register'),
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to pass the form class into the as_view() method directly as in the following example:

```
url(r'^user/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(
    form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
    name='registration_register'),
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete urls.py for this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'django_registration_demo.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # enable unique email registration feature
    url(r'^accounts/register/$',
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
        name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls'))
)
```

I've also create a complete demo for django-registration, which enables unique email feature , see: 
https://github.com/xiaohanyu/django-registration-demo